# Randomly Show Strings From ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How to Randomly Show Strings From ArrayList and Remove it from array after Show when click button, or Call Function.

```
` Questions = new ArrayList<String>();
    q1 = "I value learning and knowledge.  I am self- reliant and expect the same of others.";
    Questions.add(q1);
    q2 = "I am vitally interested in the development of my own potentials and open to learning. I respect the needs and values of others and I am willing to give help and contribute";
    Questions.add(q2);
    q3 = "I am excited by the challenge of experimentation and discovery. I believe that the pursuit of knowledge for its own sake is important.";
  Questions.add(q3);
    q4 = "I tend to be an observer in most situations. I give a lot of space to others and do not interfere unless invited to join in.";
 Questions.add(q4);
    q5 = "I tend to be a loner, and enjoy a deep conversation with people who show a genuine interest in things I am interested in.";
Questions.add(q5);
    q6 = "I value high quality work done with care that goes into creating products and services of intrinsic worth. I dislike acting in a hasty and haphazard manner.";
    Questions.add(q6);
    q7 = "I have concerns and doubts about how I am received by others. I tend to withhold my doubts and concerns and get withdrawn when I am troubled.";
   Questions.add(q7);
    q8 = "I am a proficient knowledge creator; I like to get immersed in study and research leading to acquisition of skills and knowledge.";
    Questions.add(q8);
```

Comment: 1) `Collections.shuffle`. 2) `List.iterator`. 3) `Iterator.remove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way Get a random number, and delete the entry.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int min = 0;
int max = list.size() - 1;
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

String question = list.get(randomNum);
list.remove(randomNum);
```

The other Shuffle the list.

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(seed));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Collections.shuffle:

```
public static String getQuestion() {

    if (Questions.size() == 0)
        return null;

    Collections.shuffle(Questions);

    String question = Questions.get(0);
    Questions.remove(0);

    return question;
}
```